# How can i invoke a function within Javascript when its already invoked with onload or document.ready?

Tags: javascript, php, html, onload, document-ready

So when my php page loads I want to execute a function and right now that function looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function mytest() {
      //Some code
  });
```

This works fine but in that same java-script file i want to be able to invoke that "mytest()" function like a regular function but it doesn't work by just writing:

```
mytest();
```

Is there a way I can manually invoke this method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change code like this:

```
<?php
  /* php part */
?>
<!-- HTML PART -->
<script>
/* my fn */
function mytest() {

}
/* on load */
$(document).ready(function(){
  // call nr 1
  mytest();
  // call nr 2
  mytest();
  // etc...
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

"mytest" function inside $(document).ready(...) is not available outside. You can define "mytest" first in global scope and then invoke it in $(document).ready(...) and in anywhere you want.

```
function mytest() {
    //Some code
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    mytest();
});

...
mytest();
```